# Free Product of interpolated, free group factors

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, free-product

Let $L(\mathbb F_2)$ be the group von Neumann algebra of the free group on two generators. The interpolated free group factors of Dykema and Radulescu are defined as $L(\mathbb F_r)=L(\mathbb F_2)^{1/\sqrt{r-1}}$ for $r>1$, where $M^s$ denotes the amplification of the $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor $M$. This notation is consistent with the usual free group factors in the sense that if $r$ is an integer, then $L(\mathbb F_r)$ is isomorphic to the group von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb F_r$.

If $A=L(\mathbb F_r)$ and $B$ is a finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra with dimension $l$, living in a bigger tracial von Neumann algebra such that $A$ and $B$ are $\ast$-free, is there any formula to calculate the free product $L(\mathbb F_r)\ast B$?

Comment: I expanded on the background of the question to save your question from being closed. Feel free to revert any changes you don't agree with.

Comment: Since no answer has been posted yet, let me mention that my personal guess would be the classical formula $L(\mathbb{F}_n) \ast \mathbb{M}_m \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m^2n}) \ast \mathbb{M}_m$ still holds for interpolated free group factors. If that is the case, then $L(\mathbb{F}_t) \ast \mathbb{M}_m \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m^2t})^m = L(\mathbb{F}_2)^{m/\sqrt{m^2t-1}} = L(\mathbb{F}_2)^{1/\sqrt{t-m^{-2}}} = L(\mathbb{F}_{t-m^{-2}+1})$. This is just my guess though. Experts on the topic might be able to answer this definitely, so you might want to ask this on MathOverflow.

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks for cleaning up the typo in the question. Incidentally, I think you also have one in your comment: I guess you meant $L(\mathbb F_n)\ast M_m\cong L(\mathbb F_{m^2n})\otimes M_m$.

Comment: @MaoWao Ah, yes, you’re absolutely right. Thanks for spotting the typo. Unfortunately I can no longer edit that comment, so the typo will have to remain there.